# Is Stack Exchange a platform to discuss issues with GAMLN

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am using [GAMLN](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=154630) to migrate Lotus Notes mail to Google Apps.

There are some help forums at Google, but I would like to know if one of the sites at Stack Exchange would be a platform to discuss issues with GAMLN? And if so, what site should I use?

For the Google API's the site is Stack Overflow, but that does not seem the right place to discuss issues about GAMLN.

---

<sub>The sort of issues I would like to discuss are, for example a migration that just does not start, no info in the logs, no feedback why it is not starting.</sub>

Comment: Depends on the sort of question you want to ask.

Comment: Good point :-) In this case it is a migration that just does not start, no info in the logs, no clue why it is not starting. There are also questions I can probably answer, issues that occur in a migration but cannot be found in the documentation.

Comment: That sounds more like a support question - i.e. a bug filed with the vendor type of situation. If there are questions related to gamln on ServerFault though, that sounds like the more likely venue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well-written question about this could be okay on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

Since GAMLN is related to Google Apps, I would suggest https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

BUT: I'm not entirely sure--I'm not an avid user there. You may want to test your question against [their faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) first.

Comment: I don't think this would get much traction at [webapps.se]. That site is very much geared toward consumer products. Not that there aren't Google Apps questions there, of course. I'm not saying it's off-topic, but it may be a little too niche.